# Heun's Method - if this is the right way to solve..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is as the following. The following picture is my solution to it but I'm not sure if this is how you use Heun's method. I looked at the other questions but I was still unsure..

For a given differential equation $y'(x) = 4x-2$ and the initial conditions $x_0 = 0, y_0 = 0$, approximate $y(1)$ using Heun's method with $h=0.5$.

$$y_{i+1}= y_i + (1/2\cdot k_1 + 1/2\cdot k_2)\cdot h$$

$$k_1 = f(x_i, y_i), k_2 = f(x_i+h, y_i+k_i\cdot h)$$

$$y_1 = y_0 + (1/2\cdot k_1 + 1/2\cdot k_2)\cdot h$$

$$k_0 = f(x_0, y_0) = f(0, 0) = -2.$$
not sure about this part (do I just ignore the $y$ value)?

$$k_2 = f(x_0+h, y_0+k_1\cdot h) = f(0.5, (-0.2)\cdot0.5) = f(0.5, -0.1) = 0$$

same as above. whether I just ignore $y$ value.

$$y_1 = 0+(1/2\cdot(-2) + 1/2\cdot 0) \cdot (0.5) = (-1)\cdot0.5 = -0.5$$

Therefore, the approximate value of $y(1)$ is $-0.5$.

Please tell me where I have it wrong..

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First, I do not know why you use $k_i$ instead of $k_1$ in the second line of equations. Also, why to use $k_0$ when it is $k_1$ at $i=0$. You made a mistake by taking $f(0.5, -0.2\cdot 0.5)$ because $k_1=k_0=-2$ not $-0.2$. It does not change anything but still incorrect. The rest seems correct.

Comment: @SiXiM Thank you! I'm still not used to the Heun's method I'm getting everything mixed up T.T Thank you for your feedback! :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)